# Как достать статус пользователя/группы VK?

Tags: html, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как сделать это с Api vk - понятно, но я пытаюсь сделать без авторизации.

Как я понимаю, единственный вариант - парсить данные с данных страницы, но я не могу найти по какому запросу берутся эти данные(в данном случае статус пользователя).

Если я не ошибаюсь, то в коде страницы эти данные лежат в

```
<span id="current_info" class="current_info">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти источник этих данных или, возможно, альтернативные решения.

Comment: Да, статус лежит здесь:  ```<span id="current_info" class="current_info"><span class="my_current_info"><span class="current_text">СТАТУС</span></span></span>```. В чем у вас траблы?

Comment: @misdeed Я не очень понимаю куда отправлять запрос, если просто доставать сурс с url страницы, то там статуса нет. Не могли бы вы подсказать, пожалуйста?